# List of figures without figure numbers

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

How can I create a List of Figures which has captions and page numbers, but no figure numbers?

Comment: Do you then also don't want any figure numbers on the actual figures?

Comment: You can use the package `caption`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest answer is

```
\begingroup
\renewcommand\numberline[1]{}
\listoffigures
\endgroup
```

but of course this won't suppress the figure numbers in the captions to the figures.

A more complicated setting with **tocloft** that allows to better control the appearance is

```
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftfigpresnum{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}
\renewcommand\cftfigaftersnum{\egroup}
\setlength\cftfignumwidth{0pt}
\setlength\cftfigindent{0pt}
```

In this way the captions will start flush with the left margin.

Comment: That may be too tricky for newbies to use `\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup` ... `\egroup`. So is my previous answer `\font\dummyfont=dummy` ... `\dummyfont`.

Comment: Well, `\dummyfont` is quite tricky as well.

Comment: @egreg Excellent. Thanks. The tocloft approach worked perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

As is said by Marco, the easiest method may be to use `caption` package:

```
\usepackage[listformat=empty]{caption}
```

Also, `titletoc` or `tocloft` package will help, if you use them to modify contents format.