# How can I change the starting number for figures?

Tags: floats, numbering

Using KOMA report, figures seem to default to numbering from 0.1, 0.2, 0.3... I'd like these to start from 1,2,3 instead.

I'm using

```
 \documentclass{scrreprt}
```

Related, but don't answer my question:

- http://texblog.org/2007/07/25/counters-in-latex/
- [List of figures without figure numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23806/list-of-figures-without-figure-numbers)
- [How to change the numbering for different figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39315/how-to-change-the-numbering-for-different-figures)

**Edit:** This question: [Continuous numbering of figures and tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28019/continuous-numbering-of-figures-and-tables), was identified as a solution to my duplicate.  While that does look like a good answer, I've already successfully implemented the answer below.  It is different and does not require using another package.  As such, I prefer it.

Comment: The exist both [tag:figure] and [tag:figures] tags, both which are synonyms of the [tag:floats] tag, since the `figure` environment is a floating environment.

Comment: @Werner thanks for the additional edits, I think that helps differentiate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried adding the following lines at the beginning of your document?

```
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
```